# Scala parser combinators: parse either integer or float

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators, alternation

**EDIT: Solved, see "FIX" below**

I am trying to setup a scala parser combinator to parse either a float or an integer depending on the complexity of the number. Here is what I have currently:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

trait NumberLiteral
case class IntegerLiteral(i:Int) extends NumberLiteral
case class FloatLiteral(f:Float) extends NumberLiteral

class Parser extends JavaTokenParsers {

  def integer:Parser[IntegerLiteral] = wholeNumber ^^ {i => new IntegerLiteral(i.toInt)}
  def float:Parser[FloatLiteral] = floatingPointNumber ^^ {f => new FloatLiteral(f.toFloat)}
  //FIX: def float:Parser[FloatLiteral] = """[+-]?[0-9]*((\.[0-9]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?[fF]?)|([fF])|([eE][+-]?[0-9]+))\b""".r ^^ {f => new FloatLiteral(f.toFloat)} 

  def number:Parser[NumberLiteral] = integer | float;
  //FIX: def number:Parser[NumberLiteral] = float | integer;

}
```

I set up scalatest to test both the integer and float parsers and they both work. Here is what my testing class looks like:

```
import org.scalatest._

class ParserSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  val parser = new Parser()

  "Parser" should "parse IntegerLiteral" in {
    parser.parseAll(parser.integer, "0").get should equal (new IntegerLiteral(0))
    parser.parseAll(parser.integer, "4").get should equal (new IntegerLiteral(4))
    parser.parseAll(parser.integer, "4448338").get should equal (new IntegerLiteral(4448338))
    parser.parseAll(parser.integer, "-33").get should equal (new IntegerLiteral(-33))
    parser.parseAll(parser.integer, "-10101010").get should equal (new IntegerLiteral(-10101010))
    parser.parseAll(parser.integer, "004").get should equal (new IntegerLiteral(4))
  }
  it should "parse FloatLiteral" in {
    parser.parseAll(parser.float, "1.0").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(1.0f))
    parser.parseAll(parser.float, "0").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(0))
    parser.parseAll(parser.float, "32.3").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(32.3f))
    parser.parseAll(parser.float, "3.4e3").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(3400))
    parser.parseAll(parser.float, "-10").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(-10))
    parser.parseAll(parser.float, "-4e-4").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(-0.0004f))
    parser.parseAll(parser.float, "003.4").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(3.4f))
    parser.parseAll(parser.float, "4f").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(4))
  }
  it should "parse NumberLiteral" in {
    parser.parseAll(parser.number, "32").get should equal (new IntegerLiteral(32))
    parser.parseAll(parser.number, "32.3").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(32.3f))
    parser.parseAll(parser.number, "32f").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(32))
    parser.parseAll(parser.number, "0.33").get should equal (new FloatLiteral(0.33f))
    parser.parseAll(parser.number, "32e2").get should equal (new IntegerLiteral(3200))
    parser.parseAll(parser.number, "0").get should equal (new IntegerLiteral(32))
    parser.parseAll(parser.number, "32.3e1").get should equal (new IntegerLiteral(323))
  }

}
```

Both the `IntegerLiteral` and `FloatLiteral` tests work perfectly. As you can see, I want to parse the number as either an `IntegerLiteral` or FloatLiteral depending on whether it can be parsed as an int or a float. The first line in the `NumberLiteral` test works however I get the following error on the second line: `java.lang.RuntimeException: no result when parsing failed`. I can't figure out why the parser is throwing this error as the float parser can parse `32.3`. Am I doing something wrong in the number parser with the `integer | float`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just swap them:

```
...
def number:Parser[NumberLiteral] = float | integer //float first
...
```

Example:

```
scala> parser.parseAll(parser.number, "32.3").get
res0: NumberLiteral = FloatLiteral(32.3)
```

The reason why it didn't work in first place is that parser did parse "32" from "32.3" as integer - and unparsed tail ".3" did cause an error. You can easily see it with `parse`:

```
...
def number:Parser[NumberLiteral] = integer | float //integer first
...

scala> parser.parse(parser.number, "32.3")
res3: parser.ParseResult[NumberLiteral] = [1.3] parsed: IntegerLiteral(32)

//And here is how to get unparsed tail (".3"): 

scala> val pointer = parser.parse(parser.number, "32.3").next
pointer: parser.Input = scala.util.parsing.input.CharSequenceReader@34a2d29d

scala> pointer.source.toString.drop(pointer.pos.column - 1)
res15: String = .3
```

Comment: This causes the float parser to treat everything as a float. (The float parser will succeed on any number including integers). In this case, the test fails on the first line because `FloatLiteral(32.0) does not equal IntegerLiteral(32)`. Is there a way to cause the float parser to fail on integers?

Comment: You can define your own regex-based float parser which require mandatory `.`, like `"""[0-9]*.[0-9]*""".r`

Comment: Okay, I fiddled around a bit and came up with this regex: `[+-]?[0-9]*((\.[0-9]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?[fF]?)|([fF])|([eE][+-]?[0-9]+))\b`. It will match numbers with a decimal point and an optional "e" parameter or it will match integers with the "f" or "F" flag. Eg. Matches: `3.3, -4.12, .43, 3e3, 3.4e-4, 3.3e4f, 1e1F, 4f, -23F` Doesn't match: `0, 1, -3, 443, 3e`. After replacing the float parser with this as you said, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks @Harrison That worked perfectly for me. Could I suggest you leave this as an answer so that more people can see it